# I Need help Numeric Comparison in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have one matrix called targets (1X4000); column 1 to 2000 contains double value 0 and column 2001 to 4000 contains double value 1

a)
i want to create a matrix called targets_1 where i want to check if the value is 0 then make the entry 1 so at the end of the day i must have a matrix with :column 1 to 2000 with value 1 and column 2001:4000 with value zero

b)
Same situation as above but this time i want to check if the value is 1 then make the entry 1 and if it is zero then make the entry zero; at the end; my new matrix targets_2 contains values: column 1 to 2000 with value zero and column 2001:4000 with value 1

i know how to use the strcmp function to make such checking with strings, but problem is that my original matrix is double and i dont know if there is such function like

setosaCmp = strcmp('setosa',species);

which could work with double (numbers); any help would be appreciated

Comment: The equivalent of `strcmp` for numerical values is `eq`, or simply the `==` comparison operator. (If your numerical values are in a cell array, `cell2mat` may help, or a slightly messy approach using an anonymous function and `cellfun`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm basing this answer purely on the fact that you've mentioned `setosaCmp = strcmp('setosa', species);`. From this I'm guessing that

1. You have Statistics Toolbox, as `setosa` is a species of iris from the Fisher Iris dataset widely used in Statistics Toolbox demos, and
2. You have a variable containing class labels, and you'd like to construct some class indicator variables (i.e. a new variable for each class label, each of which is 1 when the item is in that class, and 0 when it's not).

Is that right? If not, please ignore me.

If I'm right, then I think the command you're looking for is `dummyvar` from Statistics Toolbox.  Try this:

```
>> classLabels = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3];
>> dummyvar(classLabels)
ans =
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
 1     0     0
 0     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear.  It sounds like the following would satisfy your description:

```
targets_1 = 1 - targets;
targets_2 = targets;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
targets1 = double(targets == 0);
targets2 = targets;
```